# Understanding OpenCV matrix manipulation

Tags: python, c#, opencv

I've started using opencv and I'm trying to convert some python code I found for merging a transparent image with another image into c# (opencvsharp). There is a couple of lines that i'm unsure about and hoping someone can explain (even without knowledge of opencvsharp)

This is the python code

```py
def blend_transparent(face_img, overlay_t_img):
    # Split out the transparency mask from the colour info
    overlay_img = overlay_t_img[:,:,:3] # Grab the BRG planes
    overlay_mask = overlay_t_img[:,:,3:]  # And the alpha plane

    # Again calculate the inverse mask
    background_mask = 255 - overlay_mask

    # Turn the masks into three channel, so we can use them as weights
    overlay_mask = cv2.cvtColor(overlay_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    background_mask = cv2.cvtColor(background_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    # Create a masked out face image, and masked out overlay
    # We convert the images to floating point in range 0.0 - 1.0
    face_part = (face_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (background_mask * (1 / 255.0))
    overlay_part = (overlay_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (overlay_mask * (1 / 255.0))

    # And finally just add them together, and rescale it back to an 8bit integer image    
    return np.uint8(cv2.addWeighted(face_part, 255.0, overlay_part, 255.0, 0.0))
```

I'm stuck with these 2 lines:

```py
face_part = (face_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (background_mask * (1 / 255.0))
overlay_part = (overlay_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (overlay_mask * (1 / 255.0))
```

My understanding is that `face_img * (1 / 255.0)` is multipling each element in the matrix by 1/255. Is that correct?

This is the opencvsharp code i have that works until the equivalent of those 2 lines

```cs
private Mat BlendTransparent(Mat faceImg, Mat overlay)
{
    Mat[] rgbLayer;
    Cv2.Split(overlay, out rgbLayer);
    Mat[] rgb = { rgbLayer[0], rgbLayer[1], rgbLayer[2] };
    Mat[] rgba = { rgbLayer[3] };

    var overlayImg = new Mat();
    var overylayMask = new Mat();
    Cv2.Merge(rgb, overlayImg);
    Cv2.Merge(rgba, overylayMask);

    Mat backgroundMask = 255 - overylayMask;

    Cv2.CvtColor(overylayMask, overylayMask, ColorConversionCodes.GRAY2BGR);
    Cv2.CvtColor(backgroundMask, backgroundMask, ColorConversionCodes.GRAY2BGR);

    // these 2 lines dont work the same as python
    Mat facePart = Cv2.Multiply(faceImg * (1 / 255.0), backgroundMask * (1 / 255.0));
    Mat overlayPart = Cv2.Multiply(overlayImg * (1 / 255.0), overylayMask * (1 / 255.0));

    var output = new Mat();
    Cv2.AddWeighted(facePart, 255.0, overlayPart, 255.0, 0.0, output);
    return output;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: It seems those two lines are normalizing the BGR values to lie between 0 and 1.

Comment: C# is probably following the C++ semantics and preserving the data type after the operation has been applied. Python promotes `facePart` and `overlayPart` to `float64` But C# keeps the type to `uint8`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve my issue using a normalizing function on each mat ie. ```Cv2.Normalize(faceImg , faceImg , 0, 1, NormTypes.MinMax, MatType.CV_32F);```